# Creating a custom function in apache-age?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

How can I create a custom function in apache-age,
similar to the function we can create using PostgreSQL statement;

```
CREATE FUNCTION f2(INTEGER) returns INTEGER AS 'SELECT \$1' LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I need to create a function just like the above function created in Postgresql. Input of function should be integer and output should also be integer.

Comment: Apache AGE supports the PostgreSQL wire protocol and syntax. So it shoId be possible to create custom functions using the same syntax as in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

In Apache-AGE you can create the custom function in same way as in PostgreSQL.

For this you need to use "CREATE FUNCTION" clause. A simple example of function which accepts INTEGER and returns INTEGER is as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_square(i INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
SELECT i * i;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This function is accepting INTERGER and is returning its square.
All of your function calculation goes after "SELECT" statement. For Example, if you want to subtract i after finding its square then you will modify it as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_square_subtract_i(i INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
SELECT (i * i) - i;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is supported by Apache AGE, therefore we can use the same syntax as PostgreSQL to create a custom function in Apache Age.

To create a custom function we use the CREATE statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION
function_name(argument_1 data_type, argument_2 data_type, ...)
RETURNS return_data_type AS $$
BEGIN
-- function body
END; $$
LANGUAGE language;
```

Example: function to multiply two integers:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mul(a
integer, b integer)
RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN a * b;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Once the function is created we can use it in a SQL statement.

```
SELECT mul(5, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query to retrieve id's of all the edges and vertices of a specific graph and label.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test."Node";
```

| id | properties |
| --- | --- |
| 844424930131971 | {name: 'A'} |
| 844424930131972 | {name: 'B'} |
| 844424930131973 | {name: 'C'} |

```
(3 rows)
```

`test` is graph name and `Node` is label name. Replace it with you own data.

Answer (score 0):

To create an AGE function in a similar manner as PostgreSQL functions, it is important to note that all AGE functions executed within the Cypher query `$$ $$` should have the `age_` prefix.

For instance, if you intend to create a function say `square()`, the procedure would be as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION age_square(num INTEGER) 
RETURNS INTEGER AS 
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN num * num;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can now reload the AGE extension and utilize `square()` function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
  RETURN square(13)
$$) AS (result agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the function by:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Sum(integer)
RETURNS integer AS $$
    SELECT 1+1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION
ABC(int,int) RETURNS int AS 
$$
BEGIN
RETURN a - b;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is the basic syntax and you can modify it as desired.